# Android Media Codec type "video/mp4v-es" - Is it same as MPEG-4 Part 2 (MPEG-4 Visuals)?

Tags: android, video, encoding, decode, codec

I have less knowledge on the codecs. What I know codec stands for Decode/Encode.In codecs will be built in mobiles and external libs can used as an alternative. By codecs plays big role for Audio\Video in which format have encoded as file and decoded to play them.

Problem :

Android api 16 is shipped with **MediaCodec** which can do Encoding/Decoding work. **MediaCodec** contains flags constant

> "video/mp4v-es"

Is it same as **MPEG-4 part 2 (MPEG-4 Visual Format)** codec format.

> note : There is MPEG-4 part 10 format which is (H.264 )AVC Format. I just want need confirmation or any documentation or Blogs links which can help me in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

By default "video/mp4v-es" maps to the Google's MPEG4 Part-2 Video Software Codec. See [media_codecs_google_video_xml](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/data/media_codecs_google_video.xml) for details. However on a real device, it will be  implemented by a hardware video codec as software-video-codecs are processor-intensive.

For MPEG4 Part 10 (H.264), "video/avc" has to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Its actually quite ambiguously defined but I believe that MP4V-ES is an MPEG-4 audio/visual stream which has been fragmented and mapped to RTP packets for transport using the RTP streaming protocol.

The RFC describing this outlines an efficient and pragmatic mapping of the audio and video packets to RTP packets - for example it does not simply assume that there is a one to one mapping.

More info is available in the RFC defining the format: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6416